# Restart single activity within a tabactivity

Tags: android

As title, I have read some articles. And I wrote this to do so.

```
public class TabManager {
    private static Context tabAct;
    private static final String TAG = "TabManager"; 

    public static void setTabActivity(Context t) {
        Log.i(TAG, "setTabActivity");
        tabAct = t;
    }

    public static void restart(String tid, Class act) {
        Log.i(TAG, "restart " + tid);
        LocalActivityManager manager = ((ActivityGroup) tabAct).getLocalActivityManager();
        manager.destroyActivity(tid, true);
        manager.startActivity(tid, new Intent(tabAct, act));
    }
}
```

However, when I did

```
TabManager.restart("tid4", MyActivity.class);
```

The activity was destroyed but it didn't start.
Could someone give me some advices?
Thanks!

Comment: wt error did it show in the logcat?

Comment: When i did the source above, it didn't throw any exception. And the screen didn't change anything. But when i clicked other tag and then clicked back. It throwed NullPointerException.

Comment: When u call restart, check the logcat, because you are calling `startactivity` there. so it will give some error(if not exception) about why it failed to start the activity.

Comment: thanks! but i dont receive any error or exception when i call restart

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation of the [LocalActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html#startActivity%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.Intent%29). It says calling `startActivity` will restart the activity if it meets some conditions. So the call to `destroyActivity` is not required.